# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encoding' when trying to pull transfers for a token

Tags: python, transfer, address, publickey, solana-client-sdk

I'm working on a Python script to pull successful transfers from the mint address. When I call the script below this is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/user/Documents/test12.py", line 13, in 
> response = client.get_token_accounts_by_owner(mint_pubkey, opts=opts)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/solana/rpc/api.py",
> line 860, in get_token_accounts_by_owner
> body = self._get_token_accounts_by_owner_body(owner, opts, commitment)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/solana/rpc/core.py",
> line 422, in *get_token_accounts_by_owner_body
> pubkey, filter*, config = self._get_token_accounts_convert(owner, opts, commitment)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/solana/rpc/core.py",
> line 384, in _get_token_accounts_convert
> encoding_to_use = _ACCOUNT_ENCODING_TO_SOLDERS[opts.encoding]
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encoding'

```
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solanasdk.publickey import PublicKey

# Initialize the Solana RPC client
client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com")

# Token Mint Address as a PublicKey
token_mint_address = "TOKENADDRESSHERE"
mint_pubkey = PublicKey(token_mint_address)

# Fetching token accounts by mint address
opts = {"mint": mint_pubkey}
response = client.get_token_accounts_by_owner(mint_pubkey, opts=opts)
```

I thought I would be getting a string, not a dict back. I saw a reference somewhere that said if you are not passing a PublicKey for the mint address (passing its string instead) then this would happen. I am passing the mint address as a PublicKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to manually add `encoding` value in your `opts` dictionary or simply use [TokenAccountOpts](https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/50af7e6bdf08751cdc69c3dffd96151fec742088/src/solana/rpc/types.py#L43C7-L43C23) and pass it in your options.

Specifying "encoding" for `get_token_accounts_by_owner` request is mandatory in the Solana.py library, which you are not doing right now. TokenAccountOpts already has the default encoding filled as `base64`. You can choose to enter `base58` or `jsonParsed` encoding as well for human readable response.

Solana.py reference: [get_token_accounts_by_owner](https://%20https://michaelhly.com/solana-py/rpc/async_api/#solana.rpc.async_api.AsyncClient.get_token_accounts_by_owner)

JSON RPC reference: https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettokenaccountsbyowner